# angularjs get global scope variable within javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get data from my server from an ajax request in my Angularjs controller then access the data through another javascript file. I am using canvas and trying to grab stored data on the database through my angularjs controller.

I store the data in a global scope variable in my angularjs controller and I am trying to access it through my canvas javascript file.

I know you can access the controller methods like this:

```
var scope = angular.element($('#Controller')).scope();
scope.$apply(function(){
      scope.getFunc();           
});
```

However whenever I try and access a global scope variable it returns in this object called [remove: function] and I do not know how to get the data from this object.

Is there a better way to get the global scope variables from Angularjs? Thanks for the help.

Comment: consider using a service, and inject it wherever it is going to be used. this way you can share data between your components.

Comment: first of all your _canvas javascript file_ must be brought part of the angular framework, best option is probably to turn it into a directive. Then, when you are using your directive under a controllers scope, it can access all controller exposed variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plunker that shows how to share data between controllers. I am linking the plunker here.

A service is a singleton object where you can store and retrieve data across controllers. This is generally the preferred way to share data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bsFxDn3RQCGlmZLJMAil?p=preview

Code of the service

```
fasterApp.service('fasterService', function($rootScope){
 var serv = {
        name: '', age: '', place: '', gender: '',
        addData: function (n, a, p, g) {
            this.name = n;
            this.age = a;
            this.place = p;
            this.gender = g;

            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataAdded');
        }
    };
    return serv;
})
```

Add data is called when data is to be added.

The following code goes in the second controller

```
$scope.$on('dataAdded', function () {
    $scope.name = fasterService.name;
    $scope.age = fasterService.age;
    $scope.place = fasterService.place;
    $scope.gender = fasterService.gender;
});
```

and the dataAdded event is recieved in the second controller after data is added.